# prototype thread concurrent conflict

Tags: javascript

I'm studying the difference between prototype and this in javascript. I found some really good posts. But I still have one question.

I understood that prototyped classes share the same function while classes declared using "this" creates a new instance of each method every time a new object is of that class is created.

If I use a multi-thread (I'm also studying how threads works in js, just for curiosity) the prototyped classes will present concurrent acess conflict if to instance of the same class call the same method at the same time?

Comment: Javascript is not a multi-thread language

Comment: Well, I understood that you can run scripts on background with Web Worker

Comment: @RafaelTeles: Then there's still only one thread running in that background web worker

Comment: @rafael Teles is probably referring to window.setTimeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is not capable of multi-threaded technologies. There are 'manipulations' that you can do to create multi-threads, but still they are not really multi-threaded.

You can have asynchronous functions that call in a loop.

```
Function 1
Function 2
Function 1
Function 2
```

In c++ & other multi-threaded capable languages you would have:

```
Function 1 & 2
Function 1 & 2
```

JavaScript is a procedural language.

---

`This` will always represent the parent object.

the hierarchy:

```
Window{
      object{
            //your code
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification